# How to get only one record for each duplicate row in SSIS

Tags: ssis, etl

How to get only one record for each duplicate row in SSIS?

I know how it works in Informatica by using:

- Aggregator Transformation
- Group by one column
- Select MAX of any other column

But I don't know how to do this in SSIS.

Answer (score 3):

The `Aggregate` component within a `Data Flow Task` might be what you're looking for. 
If you're sourcing from a database, generally, I find it better to create a query to pull only the unique data to begin with. It saves resources all around and performs better.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what billinkc has mentioned, you can solve it by introducing `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY <ID> ORDER BY <ID>` if you're using SQL-Server/Oracle. This will generate 1 for unique rows by ID and incremental values for duplicates.

Next, either filter in source SQL using `WHERE condition = 1` OR use `Conditional Split` in SSIS transformation with condition `row = 1`.

Modify your partition by and order by as per problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
WITH resultTable AS (
SELECT 
RT.*,
LT.MID
FROM MyTable RT
Inner JOIN 
(
  SELECT SEQ,Max(ID) as MID
  FROM MyTable
 GROUP BY SEQ
) LT ON RT.SEQ = LT.SEQ AND RT.ID = LT.MID)
select resultTable.* from resultTable
```

OR Arrange the rows in a certain order and take the first row, the example of which I have given below

```
WITH resultTable AS (
SELECT 
RT.*,  
ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY RT.[ColumnForGroupBy] 
                         ORDER BY RT.ID DESC ) AS [ROW NUMBER]
FROM MyTable RT
Inner JOIN 
(
  SELECT [ColumnForGroupBy]
  FROM MyTable
 GROUP BY [ColumnForGroupBy]
) LT ON RT.[ColumnForGroupBy] = LT.[ColumnForGroupBy])
select resultTable.* from resultTable
WHERE resultTable.[ROW NUMBER] = 1
```